# Json values in jQuery foreach loop

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting the following JSON response from the server:

```json
[{"id":"1","pid":"0","type":"Individual","code":"i","status":"1"},
 {"id":"2","pid":"0","type":"Group","code":"g","status":"1"},
 {"id":"15","pid":"0","type":"asdasd","code":"asd","status":"1"},
 {"id":"16","pid":"0","type":"asdas","code":"asd","status":"1"},
 {"id":"17","pid":"0","type":"my check","code":"mt","status":"1"}]
```

How can I make jQuery foreach loop and get only values of `id` and `type`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    var json = '[{"id":"1","pid":"0","type":"Individual","code":"i","status":"1"},{"id":"2","pid":"0","type":"Group","code":"g","status":"1"},{"id":"15","pid":"0","type":"asdasd","code":"asd","status":"1"},{"id":"16","pid":"0","type":"asdas","code":"asd","status":"1"},{"id":"17","pid":"0","type":"my check","code":"mt","status":"1"}]';
    $.each($.parseJSON(json), function() {
        alert(this.id + " " + this.type);
    });
```

Comment: why would you convert the object to a string and then parseJSON instead assign the object to json variable. any specific reason?

Comment: No, I thought the string has been given initially. Of course JSON if it's an object itself, shouldn't be parsed.

Answer (score 10):

```
var json = 
[
   {"id":"1","pid":"0","type":"Individual","code":"i","status":"1"},
   {"id":"2","pid":"0","type":"Group","code":"g","status":"1"},
   {"id":"15","pid":"0","type":"asdasd","code":"asd","status":"1"},
   {"id":"16","pid":"0","type":"asdas","code":"asd","status":"1"},
   {"id":"17","pid":"0","type":"my check","code":"mt","status":"1"}
];

$.each(json,function(i,el)
{
   alert(el.id+' - '+el.type);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4tLmZ/) is that stupid example running

**EDIT:**

As **enoyhs** said this could also be achieved with pure javascript which would be a faster solution.
[Here](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-jq-each-vs-foreach/2) is a benchmark of looping arrays in javascript vs jQuery:

Comment: Or you can get without jQuery with simple:
for (i in json) {
  alert(json[i].id + ' - ' + json[i].type);
}

Answer (score 2):

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/emCT8/

Snippet to create new array of objects that only contain id and type keys:

```
var json = [{"id":"1","pid":"0","type":"Individual","code":"i","status":"1"},{"id":"2","pid":"0","type":"Group","code":"g","status":"1"},{"id":"15","pid":"0","type":"asdasd","code":"asd","status":"1"},{"id":"16","pid":"0","type":"asdas","code":"asd","status":"1"},{"id":"17","pid":"0","type":"my check","code":"mt","status":"1"}];

var arr = [];
$.each(json, function(key, value){
    arr.push({
        id: value.id,
        type: value.type
    });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = { "A" : {"A1": "1" } };
        $.each(x, function(i,v) {
            alert(i);
            console.log(i);
        });
});
</script>
```