# Convert Json to ul and li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I Have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "qA": [
        {
            "question": "How deep is the ocean",
            "answer": [
                "quite deep",
                "very deep",
                "no deep at all"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "How high is the sky",
            "answer": [
                "real high",
                "high enough",
                "not that high"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to load it into a `ul` where the question is the title of the `ul` and the answers are its `li`. How do I do that?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743866/json-values-in-jquery-foreach-loop

Comment: Does a `ul` have a title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do with jquery like this:

```
$.each(data.qA, function (index, item) {
    //console.log(item);
    html += "<ul>" + item.question;

    $.each(item.answer, function (index1, item1) {
        html += "<li>" + item1 + "</li>";

    });
    html+="</ul>";
});
$("#container").append(html);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/SLHTA/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use knockoutjs, or any other templating solution to do this. Here's how you'd go about it using knockoutjs.

```js
var data={
    "qA": [
        {
            "question": "How deep is the ocean",
            "answer": [
                "quite deep",
                "very deep",
                "no deep at all"
            ]
        },
        {
            "question": "How high is the sky",
            "answer": [
                "real high",
                "high enough",
                "not that high"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js">
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-bind="foreach:$root.qA">
        <div data-bind="text:$data.question"></div>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:$data.answer">
          <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

I would look at javascript templating libraries.  These are designed to help you express your data in the DOM.

Without a templating library, you could do something down & dirty like this:

```
function generateQuestionList(questionObject)
{

    var listContainer = document.getElementById("your-id-here");

    var heading = document.createElement("h1")

    heading.innerHTML = questionObject.question;

    var newList = document.createElement("ul");


    for(var i = 0 ; i < context.answer.length ; i ++)
        {

            var newListItem = document.createElement("li");

            newListItem.innerHTML = context.answer[i];

            newList.appendChild(newListItem);

        }

    listContainer.appendChild(heading);
    listContainer.appendChild(newList);

}
```